# What is the Annotation class used to get result data from matched token in Stanford CoreNLP TokensRegex?

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using C# and this is code snippet of how I have tried to get the results based on Stanford Corenlp documentation.

I have no idea which Annotation to use for this:

```
Annotation document = new Annotation(input);
pipeline.annotate(document);

var sentences = document.get(new CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation().getClass()) as ArrayList;

foreach (CoreMap sentence in sentences)
{
    var tokens = sentence.get(new CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation().getClass()) as ArrayList;

    TokenSequencePattern pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile("([ner: PERSON]+) /was|is/ /an?/ []{0,3} /painter|artist/");
    TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        String matchedString = matcher.group();
        var matchedTokens = matcher.groupNodes() as ArrayList;

        foreach (CoreLabel matchedToken in matchedTokens)
        {
            //matchedToken.get(new CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation().getClass()));
            //Which Annotation class to use in order to get result data from matched token?
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would like to get.  Each token in `matchedTokens` has the same annotations as other tokens in the sentence.

If you want to get the first capture group (the `([ner: PERSON]+)` part), then you should use `matcher.group(1)` or `matcher.groupNodes(1)`.  See http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/tokensregex/BasicSequenceMatchResult.html for other functions on the matched result.

Comment: I assumed matchedTokens had special annotations not found in CoreAnnotations but this clears my confusion. Thanks for the clarification.